# When debugging, is there any way to get Visual Studio to load DLLs for my Web API project without opening a browser window

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

I can make Visual Studio open my ASP.NET Web API in a new browser window, but that's annoying because I don't want a browser window to pop up. I want to go straight to Postman and start hitting endpoints.

Ideally I'd like to have Visual Studio try to run an endpoint (e.g. http://localhost:54292/token) silently in the background, which will trigger the loading of most of the DLLs I need automatically.

I know I can use the "start external program" feature and use something like cURL, but this opens a command window in the foreground, which is also annoying.

Is there any way to hide the command window, run my program minimized, or make it eager load DLLs when debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Choose the option "Don't open a page.  Wait for a request from an external application", then use Postman after starting your debug session.

Alternatively, write a new windows form application and set that as the startup project.  In that application, call the url you are interested in and remove the default form.  It will have no GUI.

You could also have the web application itself make a call into itself on startup by putting that code in your startup (globax.asax or startup.cs).  You would probably want to remove this on deploy though, hence why I'd suggest a separate application.

Comment: I know I can do this, but the point of this is that I want it to do it instantaneously to shave a few seconds off my load time while I switch to Postman.

Comment: You say "I want it to do it instantaneously".  What is "it"?

Comment: Also, @Slothario, see my update.  That'll cause the application to load, which I assume is what you're wanting.

Answer (score 0):

please try below line of code if it helps you

```
            var proc1 = new ProcessStartInfo();
            proc1.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
            proc1.Verb = "runas";
            proc1.Arguments = "/c " + command;
            proc1.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            Process.Start(proc1);
```